# Iphone view touch issue

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have issue with view touch in iphone in my application
the bottom part of my application do nothing like following.
[image]

[image]

This are two images so you can get the idea. i am not able to interact with this bottom part . and in all view of my application.
is anyone face this issue?
thanks in advance

Comment: Can't say exactly what's the problem. Do you have any transparent views bottom of the screen?. Do you add any views during the run of your app?. Need to see some code.

Comment: no nothing... I double check that already

Comment: Very difficult to tell without code sample. I can only tell you possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solve the issue

if any one facing the same issue what i had just take care of following things:

1)Make the parent view's Autosizing property to true like this:
  [image]

You can find it in size inspector.
2)For child view just do this.

```
 self.vwTextFont.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

here `vwTextFont` is my `tableview` as you can see in above image in question part and its parent view is `vwTabBar`.
   so I perform first step to `vwTabBar` and second step to `vwTextFont`.
Hope this will help.